# Is "getSomething()" a bad method naming pattern?

Tags: oop, coding-style, naming-conventions

Methods should tell objects what to do, for example:

```
circle.paint()
```

But if I tell an object to `getSomething()`, I would tell the object to *get* "something" (from anywhere) and **not** to *return* "something", what is the typical usage of `get` methods (`getName()` would return "name").

I think that it would be more correct to name the method `returnSomething()`.

So is `get` (as used typically) a bad naming pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The convention probably varies depending on the language you are using, in php (which doesn't support getter/setter methods) the following is quite common:

`$myObject=>setSomething($value)` - sets an internal variable of $myObject representing 'something' to $value

`$myObject=>getSomething()` - returns an internal variable of $myObject representing 'something'

This is less common in languages like C#, which support getter/setter methods, where you'd probably do the following:

```
public object Something {
  get { return _something; }
  set {  _something = value; }
}
```

Then you can use dot syntax to access the private variable:

```
myObject.Something="something";
string value=myObject.Something;
```

Comment: That is like the Java convention, but maybe these conventions are bad in terms of oop.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't use `Get` prefix.

Only prefix I do use for methods that retrieves something is `Is` for "indicators".
E.g. payment.IsOverdue()

As for setter methods - those shouldn't exist.
Object state should be defined by itself through invoked behavior.

`Get` is not necessary because when we are asking for something, nouns should be used for naming.

Comment: Maybe `get` is only a poor workaround for languages without properties.

Answer (score 0):

Deamon, first of all I think this thing kinda depends on the language.Secondly, I've got this [Method Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for you.

> The following are examples of
>   correctly named methods.
>
> RemoveAll()
>
> GetCharArray()
>
> Invoke()

I can also say that in the company I am working we always use names like `GetSomething()`, `GetYourAcceptRateHigher()` for our methods.